# Get page IDs based on which template they are using?

Tags: widgets, templates

I have a situation where I need to provide a dropdown of pages in a widget, based on whether they are using a specific template. In other words, for all pages using template 'Foo', get the post ID.

I have coded the rest of the widget, but I'm using an input field for entering a page ID (which can get messy with non-technical users, having to figure out the page ID to use) - I would much rather provide a select box with the page title of the pages using the specific template.

I have tried getting the WP_Query object with this:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'meta_key' => '_wp_page_template',
    'meta_value' => 'templates/_partner.php'
));
```

The meta value is corrent (corresponds to 2 entries in the database), but I don't get any results on the widget page. The select box is empty.

Can you not call WP_Query from a widget, or do I need to look elsewhere for this solution?

**UPDATE**
I checked the $the_query->request for the SQL that runs this, and it returns no rows. It turns out that I was missing the 'post_type' => 'page' in the query.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

WP_Query goes only through posts by default.

Try adding `page` as your post type:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type'  => 'page',  /* overrides default 'post' */
    'meta_key'   => '_wp_page_template',
    'meta_value' => 'templates/_partner.php'
));
```

See: [WP_Query - Type Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query#Type_Parameters)

Comment: @Calle no prob - it happens all the time :) I would love to see `any` as the default value but that would probably make internet explode :P

Answer (score 2):

You can use `wp_dropdown_pages()` to directly create a drop-down list of the pages you would like to display:

```
$args = array(
    'name' => '_partner_page', // "name" attr of the <select> element
    'id' => 'partner-page', // id attr of the <select> element
    'hierarchical' => 1, // set to 0 for flat display
    'echo' => 1, // set to 0 to return
    'selected' => $post->ID, // ID of the option with "selected" attr, set to 0 to disable
    'meta_key' => '_wp_page_template',
    'meta_value' => 'templates/_partner.php'
);
wp_dropdown_pages($args);
```

There are alot of agruments you can pass to `wp_dropdown_pages()`. Besides the ones on the [codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_pages) of this function, you also can pass any argument listed on [`get_pages()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages) function, as `wp_dropdown_pages()` uses `get_pages()` to retrieve the list of pages that will be displayed as dropdown list.

Comment: When I add the `meta_key` and `meta_value` arguments to my `wp_dropdown_pages` function, no element is outputted. The values are correct, and the template file is specified and exists. I Don't believe these arguments are supported.

Answer (score 2):

```
$query= new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type'  => 'page',  /* overrides default 'post' */
    'meta_key'   => '_wp_page_template',
    'meta_value' => 'page-templates/{template name}.php'
));
```

This worked for me because my custom theme used *page-templates* folder.